# PHP-FPM + PHP-5.2.14 + NGINX - Giving 404

Tags: apache-2.2, php, nginx, php-fpm, php-cgi

I've been slaving away trying to get PHP working via PHP-FPM. One of our servers is getting hit by slowloris is apache cant handle it.

I got NGINX running all fine and passing data back to apache but now Im trying to go pure NGINX atleast for most stuff.
I installed PHP-5.2.14 from source and patched with PHP-FPM for 5.14 with configured with the ff:

`'./configure' '-enable-fastcgi' '--enable-fpm' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/usr/com' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--with-pear=/usr/share/pear' '--with-bz2' '--with-curl' '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-png' '--with-pspell' '--with-expat-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr/include' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-track-vars' '--enable-trans-sid' '--enable-yp' '--enable-wddx' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--with-unixODBC=shared,/usr' '--enable-memory-limit' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-dbx' '--enable-dio' '--with-mime-magic=/etc/httpd/conf/magic' '--without-sqlite' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--with-xml' '--without-tidy' '--with-mhash=shared,/usr' '--with-mcrypt=shared,/usr' '--without-mssql' '--without-oci8' '--without-mysql' '--without-gd' '--without-odbc' '--disable-dom' '--disable-dba' '--without-unixODBC' '--disable-pdo' '--disable-xmlreader' '--disable-xmlwriter' '--disable-json'`

ran php-fpm and setup the config properly to listen on 127.0.0.1:9000 , using the user apache since thats what most of my dirs are grouped into

I have the following fastcgi configuration for NGINX:

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;

fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

and my NGINX site config:

```
server {
    server_name  website.com *.website.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/website.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/website.com.error.log;

    root /home/website.com/public_html;

    # if file doesnt exist pass to @proxy
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
    }

    # dont log static images and set expiry
    location ~* \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png|css|js|ico)$ {
        try_files $uri @proxy;
        access_log off;
        expires 7d;
    }

    # send php and other files to apache
    location ~* \.(php|shtml)$ {
    #        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
    # proxy to Apache
    location @proxy {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

When i try to access a test php page i get a 404 response..... help please if anyone know :)

Comment: PHP 5.3.3 has PHP-FPM built in. Perhaps its a better fit?

Comment: Tried installing 5.3.3 but im on RHEL 4 and my libevent is not updated and I couldnt get libevent working from source.

Answer (score 5):

Problem is that you do not have SCRIPT_FILENAME defined. You should include fastcgi.conf instead of fastcgi_params. If you do not have fastcgi.conf then your nginx version is outdated and you really should upgrade.

Comment: Thanks you were right, I didnt have SCRIPT_FILENAME defined. It works great now! Thank you

Comment: Good to know! It is customary then to accept the answer using the checkbox. :)